# Asterisk Followme() extension not found

Tags: asterisk

Can't get beyond the error message that the "extension doesn't exist" that I see in the Asterisk CLI console.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

The error message:

```
[Aug 10 01:51:54] ERROR[28026][C-00000002]: app_followme.c:1038 findmeexec: Extension '6002@default' doesn't exist
```

My followme.conf:

```
[350]
music    => default
context  => default
;context => hand      ; Tried this as well
number   => 6002
```

And extensions.conf:

```
[hand]
exten => _16175551212,1,Answer()
same  => n,wait(2)
same  => n,Background(anything-research)
same  => n,WaitExten()

exten => 1,1,Answer()
same  => n,Dial(SIP/350,4)
same  => n,wait(1)
same  => n,Playback(monty)
same  => n,Macro(voicemail,SIP/350)
same  => n,Hangup()

exten  => 2,1,Answer()

;same  => n,Dial(SIP/350,4)                              ;tried with and withou this line
;same  => n,GotoIf($[“${DIALSTATUS}” = “NOANSWER”]?:4:5) ; tried with and without this line

same   => n,Followme(350)
same   => n,Playback(monty)
same   => n,VoiceMail(2)
same   => n,6,Hangup
```

And sip.conf

```
[2]
type=peer
context=default
host=dynamic
secret=mysecretword
disallow=all
allow=ulaw

[350]
type=peer
context=hand
host=dynamic
secret=mysecretword
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
```

Thanks for any suggestions. I'm at the stage of just making random changes and hoping things will start to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your followme.conf, you created a followmeid 350, which dials the extension 6002 in the context default (or hand). The followmeid has no relation to the extension to dial. You need to have either a pattern (like _6XXX) or the extension 6002 declared in the context you are trying yo use.

Your hand context has only 3 extensions:

- 16175551212
- 1
- 2

You could create something like this (considering you are trying to reach user SIP 350):

`exten => 6002,1,Dial(SIP/350)`

or

`exten => _6XXX,1,Dial(SIP/350)`

Just make sure to add any of those lines inside the hand context and change the followmeid to use that context.

Quick tip: The leading underscore in the exten statement is only needed when you are using patterns.

Comment: Copying your code into extensions.conf and making the change to followme.conf worked without my understanding too much.

Comment: I wasn't able to have this work using followme to an outside number. I just entered the outside number the same as an inside extension.

Comment: Do you have connectivity to the PSTN? If you do, what kind of trunk do you have, could you show me your configuration? (don't forget to erase sensitive data)

Comment: Got everything working thanks to MarcZink and lots of trial and error. Can't say what I did that got it working, just that it's possible.